# install new foundation email occurred error

Tags: zurb-foundation, email-templates

I Want to install new [Foundation Email](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/getting-started.html) framework as said in [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/sass-guide.html#installing).

Step one has No problem, But when I run `foundation new --framework emails` to fire up a blank Foundation for Emails project, This error has occurred:

> ERROR: "foundation new" was called with arguments ["--framework",
>   "emails"]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try `foundation new`, their CLI will guide you. Details here: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the ruby cli is installed on your machine. See [this issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-6/issues/241).

I was able to fix by uninstalling with `gem uninstall foundation` and rebooting console as recommended there.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try just calling `foundation new` and select the email framework from there